# Repair URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, uri

My web app has an input field where the user can enter a link to their website. Often times they input something like `Twitter.com/mhluska` which is not a valid URL. I'd like to automatically repair it to `https://twitter.com/mhluska`.

But the URL can point to any domain name.

I've tried using the `a` tag to parse the URL but it just appends it as a path local to the current origin:

```
const elem = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'Twitter.com/mhluska';
console.log(a.href); // "http://localhost:3000/some/path/Twitter.com/mhluska"
```

I've looked into some URL parsing libraries but they often just throw an error for invalid URLs. Including the native [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

Is there a simple way to attempt to create a valid link out of whatever garbage the user may input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL relative notation. The hostname in a URL is case insensitive and modern browsers will change case in href strings.

```js
const elem = document.createElement('a');
elem.href = '//Twitter.com/mhluska';
console.log(elem.href);
```

Comment: your answer saved me from writing a lot of code checks